# Android: Spinner inside LinearLayout causes crash

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-linearlayout

I'm working on a simple app that reads from a sensor and displays a weight. I wanted to include a spinner so I could display the weight in different units. I was able to get a spinner working by itself, but when I included it in a LinearLayout, the app crashes immediately upon launch. I'm sure there's a simple explanation, but I'm totally new to programming for Android and I don't know what to look for.

Here's my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.com.example.testapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<String> difficultyLevelOptionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.units_spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.units_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.com.example.testapp.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Callibrate"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:text="100"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/units_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally my strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">The Name Of Your App Goes Here</string>
    <string name="calibrate_button">Calibrate</string>
    <string name="cal_hint">Calibration Weight</string>
    <string-array name="units_array">
        <item>lb</item>
        <item>kg</item>
        <item>ton</item>
        <item>oz</item>
        <item>g</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

So here's the question: Why does the spinner work fine when it's not in the LinearLayout, but crashes when I put it inside the LinearLayout?

P.S. Please forgive (or edit) my formatting. I'm fairly new to stack-overflow as well.

Comment: Hard to say without the stacktrace

Comment: can you copy the logcat message  here please , and are you declaring a spinner in the activity_main.xml ?? i can not see it

Comment: @AIL it's the last view in the last LL. Right before the ViewGroup end tags...scroll down

Comment: There's a few things in things  your code ,
- you are not specifying the linear `LayoutOrientation` 
-Generally when we use weight you  better specify what element attribute you want to distribute the weight on 
-using match_parent inside wrap_content is generally not recommended design use .